# Handle the touch event within a moved layer in cocos2d-x cpp project?

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

In my project, I have a layer that contains a lot of CCLabelTTF. And layer can be moved left or right. I have implemented three ccTouch Event. And now I want to add touch event to every CCLabelTTF. When users touch the CCLabelTTF and come to another scene. What can I do? 
Thank you ahead.

[image]

```
bool  ccTouchBegan(CCTouch *pTouch, CCEvent *pEvent);
void  ccTouchEnded(CCTouch *pTouch, CCEvent *pEvent);
void  ccTouchMoved(CCTouch *pTouch, CCEvent *pEvent);
```

following details：

```
bool  WallScene::ccTouchBegan(CCTouch *pTouch, CCEvent *pEvent)
{
touchbeginpoint = ccp(pTouch->getLocation().x , pTouch->getLocation().y);
touched=true;
return true;
}
void  WallScene::ccTouchEnded(CCTouch *pTouch, CCEvent *pEvent)
{
touched=false;
}
void  WallScene::ccTouchMoved(CCTouch *pTouch, CCEvent *pEvent)
{
CCPoint newpos=ccp(pTouch->getLocation().x , pTouch->getLocation().y);
CCPoint temppoint=ccp(newpos.x-touchbeginpoint.x, newpos.y-touchbeginpoint.y);
changepoint =ccp(changepoint.x+temppoint.x, changepoint.y+temppoint.y);
////////////////
CCSize visibleSize = CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getVisibleSize();

if(changepoint.y!=0)
    changepoint.y=0;

if(changepoint.x>=0)
    changepoint.x=0;

if (changepoint.x<=-3000*rescale+visibleSize.width)
    changepoint.x=-3000*rescale+visibleSize.width;
////////////////
this->setPosition(changepoint);
touchbeginpoint = newpos;
}
```

Comment: any reason not to use a CCMenu with CCMenuItemLabel objects instead of CCLabelTTF ?

Comment: @YvesLeBorg I have so many Labels that I cannot put them all in to CCMenu.

Comment: that is like saying 'I have so many sprites that i cant put them all in an app' ... you add the labels as children to something, what is the difference ?

Answer (score 0):

create a subclass of CCLabelTTF and override the touch methods in that class and do whatever you want to in those methods.